# How to delete files from a folder using a list of file names in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, batch-file

i have a folder with 2K+ files in it, i need to delete around 200, i have a txt file with all the file names i need removed ordered in a list, how do i remove the specific files from the folder using the list? (OS is windows 7)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple way is copy the txt file to a file called `mydel.bat` in the directory of the files to delete. Using an editor like Microsoft Word edit this file. Do a global replace on Newline normally `^p` in Word. Replace it with `space/f^pdelspace`. This will change

```
File1.bin
File20.bin
File21.bin
```

to (with `/f` for "force delete read-only files"):

```
File1.bin /f
del File20.bin /f
del File21.bin /f
del
```

Edit the fist line to add the `del` space
and delete the last line.

Run the batch command.

Comment: Apart from the /Y switch, which apparently doesn't work in win7 del command, this worked quite well .. thanks

Comment: That's probably supposed to be `/f` for "force delete read-only files" instead of `/y`.

Comment: Correct afrazier. I was mixing up the /Y which works with XCOPY and one or two other DOS programs to 'Suppress prompting to confirm action'

Comment: In editors who know how to do find/replace with regex, such as Notepad++, you would need to replace "^" with "del " and "$" with " /f", where ^ represents the beginning of each row and $ - the end.

Comment: or via a Spreadsheet / Excel filenames in 1st column then `="del "&A1` in the 2nd `Ctrl+Shift+End` to select to last row > `Ctrl+D` to "fill down" 
"Copy & Paste" new column into +new sheet > "123 Values" > "File > Save As..." so just deleted 3672 duplicate files using the .txt file generated with free "CCcleaner" tool. Yielding 71GB of space.

Answer (score 45):

Type this on the command line, substituting your file for `files_to_delete.txt`:

```
for /f %i in (files_to_delete.txt) do del %i
```

A version of this suitable to include in `.cmd` files (double %%) and able to deal with spaces in file names:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (files_to_delete.txt) do del "%%f"
```

Comment: This actually deleted the file list instead of the files themselves ... i had to create the list again :|

Comment: My deepest apologies. I forgot the `/f` flag.

Comment: That's pretty nifty, I didn't know the command line supported loops like that. Care to write a blog post for the SU blog about this and other intricacies of the command line?

Comment: @Ivo: You might want to take a look at http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm or http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch to learn more.  Like Unix, much of what can be done in scripts (batch files) can also be done directly from the command-line.

Comment: I created a bat file and copied the 2nd example: result: the files_to_delete.txt is still removed. (even with the /f flag)

Comment: the first approach does not seem to work correct if the file containing the list has files with spaces in them.

Answer (score 24):

Using PowerShell:

```
Get-Content c:\path\to\list.txt | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Wow, that's way more readable than batch.

Comment: For future readers... I had to change the pipe operator to a `>` to make this work.  I.e. `Get-Content c:\path\to\list.txt > Remove-Item` ... I had full UNC paths in my `list.txt`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @NateJ I tried using the `>` and it just created a file for me, instead of deleting things.

Comment: @BrianJ hmm, I’ll have to check back on what I did.. good catch.

Answer (score 2):

First method works after some changes:

1. open Notepad
2. copy all file names with extension which need to be deleted after adding `del` at the beginning like

   ```
   del File1.bin
   del File20.bin
   del File21.bin
   ```
3. save the file as `xyz.bat` in the same folder
4. run the file

Comment: ...the text file in the question has about 200 file names in it. Why add `del` manually like you're proposing, while solutions were already posted to automate it? As an aside: any sane editor would have some support for searching and replace including line endings (or line starts, using regular expressions), macros, or for [block or column mode editing](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html) (often initiated by holding down Option or Alt and then selecting a block, after which one can just type on multiple lines at once).

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it can be done with powershell.

Knowing [Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), I tend to use it for this sort of thing

```
perl -l -n -e "unlink" filenames.txt
```