# Program for remove exact duplicate files while caching search results

Tags: windows, file-management, deduplication

We need a Windows 7 program to remove/check the duplicates but our situation is somewhat different than the standard one for which there are enough programs.

We have a fairly large **static** archive (collection) of photos spread on several disks. Let's call them Disk A..M. We have also some disks (let's call them Disk 1..9)  which contain **some** duplicates which are to be found on disks A..M.

We want to add to our collection new disks (N, O, P... aso.) which will contain the photos from disks 1..9 but, of course, we don't want to have any photos two (or more) times.

Of course, theoretically, the task can be solved with a regular file duplicate remover but the time needed will be very big.

**Ideally, AFAIS now, the real solution would be a program which will scan the disks A..M, store the file sizes/hashes of the photos in an indexed database/file(s) and will check the new disks (1..9) against this database.**

However I have hard time to find such a program (if exists).

Other things to note:

- we consider that the Disks A..M (the collection) doesn't have any duplicates on them
- the file names might be changed
- we aren't interested in approximated (fuzzy) comparison which can be found in some photo comparing programs. We hunt for *exact* duplicate files.
- we aren't afraid of command line. :-)
- we need to work on Win7/XP
- we prefer (of course) to be freeware

Comment: How many files and bytes are on disks A..M?

Comment: @Dennis: Do you need an exact number? An estimate would be: 400-500k files taking ~ 4-5 TB

Comment: I tried a few tools (most already listed [here](http://superuser.com/q/8223 "Which duplicate files and folders finders exist for Windows?")), but none seems to do *exactly* what you want. A command-line based approach is probably the best solution, but I need additional information to suggest one. 1) Can you access the disks simultaneously? 2) Approximately how many disks A..M and 1..9 are there? 3) Is this a one-time thing or do you want to store the database for future uses?

Comment: Answering: 1.) No, I cannot access the disks simultaneously. But, well, perhaps a kludge can be used. 2.) Now we have 5 (five) disks which are ok (the disks A..M in my example) but an "unknown" number of disks which needs checking. However, I estimate the number of these disks (IOW the 0..9 disks in my example) to 5-6. 3.) Yes, I want to store the db for future use. However I think (ok, I hope) that the "main cleaning" will happen only once.

Comment: *> However I have hard time to find such a program (if exists).*   Probably because simply moving or renaming files will render the cache useless. The file still exists, but now must be re-cached. I suppose it would still be better for all the files that have not been renamed or moved, but unfortunately nobody seems to have bothered to implement a cache (though I did consider it for my own DFF program which I abandoned after finding AllDup).

Comment: @Synetech: As I said pretty clearly I think in the body of the question, the archive is static. Hence no renames, no moves (ok, theoretically it can happen but it will be very rare).

Comment: *Your* collection is irrelevant. I wasn’t talking about you and your issue; I was *explaining* why such a program does not (or is unlikely to) exist, hence the comment and not an answer. You may have set the files to read-only and write-protected the disk, but nobody who has written DFF programs has bothered to implement a cache because that is not a common scenario and a cache would usually be of little use. If you want someone to write a custom program for your specific scenario, then you are always free to commission a developer to do so (for a price) or write one yourself.

Comment: Oh, the irony!  I'm in the process of polishing up a program that does exactly what you want.  It saves hashes of everything it looks at and thus when run again it doesn't take ages to check everything.  I wrote it originally for exactly this sort of scenario--not taking forever when you add stuff to a large collection.  I was surprised at the lack of a commercial solution that worked this way.

Comment: And I find that it looks like someone did wake up to the need: http://www.duplicate-file-detective.com/v4/new.htm  (I have **not** tried this, I just stumbled on it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Dennis solution, we decided to use the [hashdeep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) suite which is also available on Windows.

Basic usage:

Step 1. Generate the hashes (this should be done only once)

```
hashdeep64 -c tiger -r "D:\*" > Disk_D.hash
```

We use *tiger* as a hash function - [faster](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html) and better than SHA-1 (no collisions).

Step 2: Hunt for duplicates (this must be executed for each drive / directory to check)

```
hashdeep64 -k Disk_D.hash -m -r "E:\My-Dir-To-Check\*" > Dupes.txt
```

Now all the duplicates are stored in `Dupes.txt`

You can use MsWord, LibreOffice or Notepad++ (or any other way you know) to insert `del` (and/or any other options) in this text file in order to delete the files. You have [here](https://superuser.com/questions/355584/how-to-delete-files-from-a-folder-using-a-list-of-file-names-in-windows) enough variants, including a simple .bat file which scans the file list in order to delete all the entries.

Also, you have the choice to review the file list and do the processing manually.

Answer (score 2):

#### Aproach

1. Choose a collision-free hash function.

   My example uses SHA1, since the bottleneck is going to be the hard drive anyway.

   If that takes too long, it would be possible to compare only the first megabyte of the files. That *should* be enough for images.
2. Read the files of interest on the disks A..M, compute their hashes and store them in a file specific to that disk (so you can add/remove disks later).
3. Read the files of interest on the disks 1..9 and compute their hashes.

   If a file's hash is already known, perform action (list or delete).

#### Setup

1. Download and install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), a collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows.
2. In Windows Explorer, open the folder `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Cygwin\home\%USERNAME%`.
3. Edit the file `.bashrc` and append the following line:

   ```
   export PATH=~:$PATH
   ```
4. Create a file called `hashdrive` and save the following code into it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   DRIVELETTER=$(echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
   EXTENSIONS=$(echo $2 | sed 's/,/\\|/g')
   DRIVENAME=$(echo $3 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

   set -e
   [ -d /cygdrive/$DRIVELETTER ] || (echo "Drive $DRIVELETTER: does not exist." ; exit 1)
   [ -f ~/drives/$DRIVENAME ] && (echo "Hashfile for drive $DRIVENAME already exists." ; exit 1)
   set +e

   mkdir ~/drives 2>/dev/null
   find /cygdrive/$DRIVELETTER -type f -iregex ".*\.\($EXTENSIONS\)" -exec sha1sum {} \; | cut -b -40 > ~/drives/$DRIVENAME
   ```
5. Create a file called `checkdrive` and save the following code into it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   DRIVELETTER=$(echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
   EXTENSIONS=$(echo $2 | sed 's/,/\\|/g')
   ACTION=$(echo $3 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

   set -e
   [ -d /cygdrive/$DRIVELETTER ] || (echo "Drive $DRIVELETTER: does not exist." ; exit 1)
   set +e

   IFS=":" ; for FILE in `find /cygdrive/$DRIVELETTER -type f -iregex ".*\.\($EXTENSIONS\)" -printf %p:`; do
       [ "$(grep -m 1 $(sha1sum "$FILE" | cut -b -40) ~/drives/*)" ] && $ACTION "$FILE"
   done
   ```

#### Usage

- To save the hashes of all images of a certain disk to a file, start Cygwin and execute the following command:

  ```
  hashdrive DRIVELETTER EXTENSIONS DRIVENAME
  ```

  For example, if DiskA is mounted as drive `D:` and you want to hash all images with extensions `jpg` and `png`, use the following command:

  ```
  hashdrive d jpg,png diska
  ```

  There must be **no** space in `jpg,png`.
- To check a disk for duplicate images, start Cygwin and execute the following command:

  ```
  hashdrive DRIVELETTER EXTENSIONS ACTION
  ```

  For example, if Disk1 is mounted as drive `E:` and you want to list all duplicate images with extensions `jpg` and `png`, use the following command:

  ```
  checkdrive e jpg,png echo
  ```

  If you want to remove the files directly, use `rm` instead of `echo`.
- To remove a disk from the database, just delete the file `DRIVENAME` in the folder `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Cygwin\home\%USERNAME%\drive`.

#### Caution

The `rm` command does **not** move files to the Recycle Bin; it deletes them directly.

While it should be possible to recover the files anyway, be careful when using the `rm` action and try `echo` before you use `rm`.

Comment: I'm getting mixed results. On my Linux machine, things run 9 times faster than on my Win7 machine. I *hope* it's due to the fact that the hard drives of the Linux machine are faster, but it's also possible that things run smoother with a *real* Linux. Possible improvements: 1) If `hashdrive` runs too slow (I have no way to check this from here), it could be made faster by hashing only the first megabyte of each file. That *should* be enough for images. 2) `checkdrive` can be made faster by grouping hashes in buckets. I'll test tommorow if it has a mayor impact.

Comment: Thanks a lot - Following loosely your solution, I've posted a full/native Windows solution (ok, it is cross-platform actually, because hashdeep runs also on *nixes). Also, I chose not to encapsulate the commands in .bat files because the commands are fairly simple. Thanks a lot, anyway. Upvoted.

Comment: Btw, Dennis SHA-1 isn't collision free. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha-1 ...but for day-by-day files work is sufficient. I chose tiger for speed gain.

Comment: SHA-1 is broken (its initial security claim of 80 bits has been reduced to 53 bits), but no actual collision has been found so far.